# Javascript : Retrieve subset of keys given start and end key

Tags: javascript, enums

I have an object to represent enums defined as

```
enums = {

    //category A
    .
    .
    .
    .
    //genders
    female: "female"
    male: "male"
    unknown: "unknown"

    //category B
    .
    .
    .
    .

    }
```

Suppose I would want to define a function that would take in (female,unknown) and get back (female,male,unknown).This is a pretty large object that I've only illustrated for sample so doing object destructuring would not work for my case. Any leads on this?

Comment: Javascript doesn't guarantee an ordering for the keys, so this probably won't work as you'd expect. What about storing these as an array?

Comment: An object is not the correct data structure for this. Although it may work in some environments, the JavaScript spec does not enforce any guarantee about object key order, and therefore the engine is allowed to rearrange object keys in any order it sees fit! As @jackarms says, if you want a guaranteed ordering of elements, you should use an array.

Comment: I don't see what destructuring has to do with enums? And why the size of the object would matter?